# Why does the Gromoll-Meyer Sphere have dimension $7$?

Tags: lie-groups, quotient-spaces, spheres

In exercise 10.33 of the book "Matrix Groups for Undergraduates" the Gromoll-Meyer sphere is described by taking the quotient of a smooth left action of $Sp(1) \times Sp(1)$ on the manifold $Sp(2)$ defined by
$$(q_1, q_2) \circ A = \begin{pmatrix}
q_1 & 0\\
0 & q_1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot A \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\overline{q}_2 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\overline{q}$ denotes the conjugate of a quaternion $q$. The point of the exercise is to show that this action is free, but I am confused about the fact that the Gromoll-Meyer sphere is 7-dimensional. By the quotient manifold theorem, shouldn't the dimension of the Gromoll-Meyer sphere be $dim(Sp(2)) - dim(Sp(1) \times Sp(1)) = 10 - 6 = 4?$ I suppose I'm confused somewhere about the dimension of $Sp(1) \times Sp(1)$ or am misinterpreting the quotient manifold theorem.

Comment: The biquotient you have described is diffeomorphic to $S^4$ and so is indeed $4$-dimensional. The Gromoll-Meyer sphere is the biquotient of $Sp(2)$ by a single copy of $Sp(1)$ embedded diagonally in $Sp(1) \times Sp(1)$ whose action you have described. I had to go back to the original article.

Comment: Thank you that makes much more sense! That detail wasn't clear to me from the exercise.

Comment: Yes, and I did get confused too when I read the post. But then I went back to the original article, and things made sense!